# Solve $xy'=\frac{y^{3} +3yx^{3}}{7y^2+x^2}$ by using $z=\frac{y}{x}$ substitution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve $$xy'=\frac{y^{3} +3yx^{3}}{7y^2+x^2}$$ by using $$z=\frac{y}{x}$$ substitution?

EDIT:
The DE was wrong, it is now right, my apologies.

I checked with wolframalpha which gave me integrals which are very complicated and therefore I must use another method, because if I don't the professor will surely understand that it wasn't work of his student. So the "easiest", "most common", "2+2=4" solution would be appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure what you checked with Wolfram Alpha. If you've done your own work, you should post it here.

Comment: Is y the independent variable here?

Comment: Sorry, I miss typed the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $ z = y/x$, then

$$z' = y' /x - y /x^2 \implies xz' + z = y'$$

\begin{align*}
xy' &= \frac{ y^3 +3yx^2}{7y^2+x^2}=\\
y'&= \frac{ (y/x)^3 + 3(y/x) }{7(y/x)^2+1 }\\
\implies xz'+z& = \frac{z^3 + 3z}{7z^2 + 1} \\
\end{align*}

In this form, the equation is separable. So you can just integrate after splitting.

Comment: I realized that I have to get solution in form $y=y(x)$. So far I have come to $$\int{-\frac{7z^2+1}{6z^3+2z} }dz=\int{\frac{dx}{x}}$$, which would correspond to $$-\frac{1}{3}ln(6z^{\frac{7}{2}} +2z^{\frac{3}{2}})=ln(x)+c$$. How can I get the solution in form $y=y(x)$?

Comment: I'd check your integration.